# What is best practice to extend class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I want to understand difference between following

```
module XYZ
  class A
  end
  class B
  end
end
```

Does class C inherit both class A and B, or I have to extend it using < ?

```
module YZZ
include XYZ
  class C < A
  end
end
```

What happens when I do following? Does it now include all classes, or just class A ?

```
module YZZ
extend XYZ
  class C < A
  end
end
```

- What is the best way to extend class C from A ?
- How can I extend class C using both A and B ?
- How can I only include class A?

Comment: What you have in your second and third code blocks is not valid Ruby.

Comment: You lack the module name. Like `module Hello; extend XYZ end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad 1., yes, C inherits both A and B when you use #include. #extend applies to class methods.

Ad 2. `class C < A`, think about it that A is merely a constant, that is assigned an object
of instance Class as value. So, of course, C becomes its subclass.

Ad 3. When you use #extend inside the 'module' statement, `self` is the module itself, and XYZ
basically gets included in its sigleton class.

As for your three bulleted questions in the end, I do not understand the first one. What is "extend class C from A"? Will `class C < XYZ::A` do? As for the second bulleted question, you can extend C "using both A and B" simply by `C.extend( XYZ )`. As for "how can you only include class A", there is no simple way to only include part of a module. If you plan to include class A separately, if it has its own concern to solve even without B, put it in a separate module and include that one. That's called separation of concerns. If you just want to cherry-pick, you could do:

```
module Something
  A = XYZ::A
end
```

And there you have a constant Something::A pointing to the same class as XYZ::A.

Comment: Thanks Boris. By "What is the best way to extend class C from A ?" I meant is; can I do C < A or C < XYZ::A ? which one is prefered way to do extend ?

Comment: Amjad, the choice between `A` and `XYZ::A` has nothing to do with `extend`. It is merely a question of accessing constants in Ruby. Fireproof way is writing `::XYZ::A` (kinda like `\xyz\a`). `XYZ::A` works as long as the namespace from which you are calling does not have another constant `XYZ` defined. `A` works only, when you are lexically in the same namespace, as the one where A has been defined. Find more study material on accessing Ruby constants, there is not enough space to expound it here.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
module XYZ
  class A
  end
  class B < A
  end
end
```

Then for including the XYZ module and extending C from A:

```
module ABC
include XYZ
  class C < A
  end
end
```